# Handling global state the functional way?

Tags: functional-programming, state, frp

In a complex interactive app (say a video game or Web app), how do you manage global state in a functional way? The article below recommends to "simply return statements about what happened." Presumably, some other component, say `ApplicationState`, should both hold the state and manage the interaction between different components. Unfortunately, no concrete examples are given, and I'm at a loss as to what the functional version of ApplicationState should look like. I'm using functional reactive programming (FRP) and Javascript.

http://prog21.dadgum.com/26.html

Comment: Hi I am researching too about handling game loop in a functional way.. how you are going with this topics.

Comment: @salc2 long story short: global state in AppState but it's just a hashmap. SideEffects are just messages that pass thru the AppState. This way *everything* goes thru AppState (useful for debugging). Something else listens to SideEffect messages and reports back results to AppState. See https://github.com/frankandrobot/rflux. This is a reactive framework for JS.